# Creating a range object from cells function

Tags: excel, vba

Most likely an extremely simple solution but I am driving myself insane trying all the different combinations of Range and Cells in order to solve this issue.

Basically I am trying to add a hyperlink to a cell that is being dynamically selected.

This works fine and I end up interacting with the cell like so:

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colnum) ' colNum is taken from Application.Match

Now I want to add a hyperlink to that cell. From all the examples I've seen online, you need to add it like so:

```
If vItm = "Ticket No" Then
With ActiveSheet
    ref = .Cells(2, colNum).Address
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=**Range(ref)**, Address:="URLGOESHERE=" & dict(vItm), _
        TextToDisplay:=dict(vItm)
    End With
End If
```

I think the part that is failing is the Anchor:= as it requires a range object. I cannot find a way of using Cells(2, colNum) to be a range object. I've tried ".Address", which i Was hopeful for but still fails.

Please put me out of my misery and educate me!

The error is "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: The error is not in your anchor.  using your setup I successfully created a link to Google: `.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range(ref), Address:="https://www.google.com/", _
        TextToDisplay:="google"`

Comment: Thanks Scott, got totally tunnel visioned on the Anchor for some reason. It was me trying to join strings with & and not +.... Agh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a With that is only the ActiveSheet, not the range portion.
Try:

```
If vItm = "Ticket No" Then
    ref = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, colNum).Address
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(2, colNum)
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ref, Address:="URLGOESHERE=" & dict(vItm), _
        TextToDisplay:=dict(vItm)
    End With
End If
```

Comment: doesn't seem to make any difference. I did try moving it down under the With, not sure how it ended up on the row before.

Comment: @Chris Accepted your edit and changed the Anchor to show "ref" specificly..

Comment: Thanks Cyril. It appears the issue was with the failed concatenated URL, not the range! I want to scream... spent longer than I care to admit trying to get this working. Thanks for your help